# Flexbox dropdown submenu

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a problem in getting the dropdown submenu effect. I need to get at the tablet resolution (768px), so that the submenu dropdown will expand to the entire width, and the links (items) are arranged in three columns, it’s already using the `flex-basis`. I know that to do this I need to set the dropdown submenu using `position: absolute`.

A small note: Link items in the dropdown submenu will be added dynamically!

But now I have a problem with setting the last menu `<li>` items with social icons.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // Toggle Nav Menu
  const btn = document.querySelector('#btnToggle');

  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.body.classList.toggle('nav-show');
    this.classList.toggle('btn-toggle--toggled');
  });

  // Toogle Dropdown Submenu
  let submenuToggle = document.querySelector('.nav__item--has-dropdown');
  let submenu = document.querySelector('.dropdown');

  submenu.classList.add('submenu--hidden');

  function dropdownMenu() {
    submenu.classList.toggle('submenu--hidden');
  }

  submenuToggle.addEventListener('click', dropdownMenu);

  // Highlight current page active menu item.
  const selector = '.nav__link';
  const elems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
  const navigation = document.querySelector('nav');

  function makeActive(evt) {
    const target = evt.target;

    if (!target || !target.matches(selector)) {
      return;
    }

    elems.forEach(elem => elem.classList.remove('active'));
    evt.target.classList.add('active');
  };

  navigation.addEventListener('mousedown', makeActive);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.social__link {
  display: block;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1400px;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}

.logo__container {
  padding: .3125rem .3125rem .625rem;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo__heart {
  flex-basis: 27%;
}

.hgroup {
  padding-left: .625rem;
}

.headline__light {
  display: none;
}

.headline {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
}

.navigation__container {
  align-items: center;
}

.header__item {
  display: flex;
}

.btn-toggle button {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
}

.btn-toggle {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  right: 20px;
  background: none;
}

.btn-toggle .line {
  background: #888;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1), opacity 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1);
  opacity: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 80%;
}

.btn-toggle .line:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: -6px;
}

.btn-toggle .line:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.btn-toggle--toggled .line:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle--toggled .line:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.btn-toggle--toggled .line:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav {
  background: #F2EFE8;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s max-height;
}

.nav-show .nav {
  max-height: 700px;
}

.nav__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #F2EFE8;
  border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.nav__item {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: .875rem;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
  letter-spacing: .0625rem;
}

.nav__item--has-dropdown .arrow::after {
  content: "\f078";
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.nav__link {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #222;
  padding: .625rem;
}

.nav__link:hover {
  background: #c2def7;
}

.nav__link.active {
  background: #abd4f8;
}

.dropdown.submenu--hidden {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #F2EFE8;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  border-top: 1px solid #888;
}

.nav__item.dropdown__item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.dropdown__item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.icon__container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav__item.social__icon {
  padding: .625rem;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.icon {
  width: 10%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .logo__heart {
    flex-basis: 25%;
  }
  .hgroup {
    flex-basis: 71%;
  }
  .headline__light {
    display: block;
    font-size: .875rem;
    text-transform: none;
  }
  .nav__list {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .nav__item {
    width: 33.33%;
    flex-basis: 33.33%;
  }
  .nav__item:nth-of-type(1) {
    order: 1;
  }
  .nav__item:nth-of-type(2) {
    order: 4;
  }
  .nav__item:nth-of-type(3) {
    order: 7;
  }
  .nav__item:nth-of-type(4) {
    order: 2;
  }
  .nav__item:nth-of-type(5) {
    order: 5;
  }
  .nav__item:nth-of-type(6) {
    order: 8;
  }
  .nav__item:nth-of-type(7) {
    order: 3;
  }
  .nav__item:nth-of-type(8) {
    order: 6;
  }
  .nav__item:nth-of-type(9) {
    order: 9;
  }
  .nav__item:nth-of-type(10) {
    order: 10;
    padding: .625rem;
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  /* ul li ul {
          visibility: hidden;
          opacity: 0;
          display: none;
        }

          ul li:hover > ul,
          ul li:focus-within > ul,
          ul li ul:hover {
            visibility: visible;
            opacity: 1;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            transition: all 0.5s ease;
            border-top: 1px solid #888;
          } */
  .nav__item--has-dropdown .dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .nav__item--has-dropdown~.nav__item.social__icon {
    /*     margin-top: 50px; */
    /*     border-bottom: 1px solid #888; */
  }
  .dropdown__item {
    flex-basis: 33.33%;
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .icon {
    width: 4%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .logo {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .logo__heart {
    flex-basis: 30%;
  }
  .hgroup {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .unboxing__trick {
    background-color: #F2EFE8;
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 calc(-50vw + 50%);
    padding: 0 calc(50vw - 50%);
  }
  .btn-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav {
    max-height: 100%;
    transition: none;
    transition-duration: 0s;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow: visible;
  }
  .nav__list {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    border-top: none;
    padding: .625rem 0;
  }
  .nav__item {
    flex-basis: auto;
    width: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .nav__item:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0) 0%, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .20) 50%, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0) 100%);
  }
  .nav__item:last-of-type {
    border-right: 0;
  }
  .nav__item:nth-of-type(1) {
    order: 1;
  }
  .nav__item:first-child::after {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav__item:nth-of-type(2) {
    order: 2;
  }
  .nav__item:nth-of-type(3) {
    order: 3;
  }
  .nav__item:nth-of-type(4) {
    order: 4;
  }
  .nav__item:nth-of-type(5) {
    order: 5;
  }
  .nav__item:nth-of-type(6) {
    order: 6;
  }
  .nav__item:nth-of-type(7) {
    order: 7;
  }
  .nav__item:nth-of-type(8) {
    order: 8;
  }
  .nav__item:nth-of-type(9) {
    order: 9;
  }
  .nav__item:nth-of-type(10) {
    order: 10;
    flex: 1 1 8%;
    padding: .3125rem 0;
  }
  .nav__item.social__icon {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .nav__link:hover {
    background: none;
    color: #b8795a;
  }
  .nav__link.active {
    background: none;
    color: #b8795a;
  }
  .icon {
    width: 25px;
  }
  /*   nav__item--has-dropdown {
            position: relative;
          }

          .nav__item--has-dropdown > .dropdown {
            display: none;
        }

          .nav__item--has-dropdown:hover > .dropdown {
            display: flex;
          }

          .dropdown {
            porition: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            top: 100%;
            right: 0;
            flex-direction: column;
            background: #000;
        }

          .dropdown__item {
            flex: 1;
        } */
  /*   ul li ul {
            background: #F2EFE8;
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
            position: absolute;
            transition: all .25s ease;
            top: 35px;
            left: 0;
          } */
  .dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    background: #F2EFE8;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-top: none;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
  }
  .nav__item.dropdown__item {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
  .nav__item.dropdown__item::after {
    display: none;
  }
  .dropdown__item+.dropdown__item::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0) 0%, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, .20) 50%, hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0) 100%);
  }
  .dropdown .dropdown__item:first-child {
    padding-top: 5px;
  }
}

@supports (position: sticky) {
  .header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <section class="container">
      <div class="header__container">
        <div class="logo__container header__item">
          <div class="logo">
            <div class="logo__heart">
              <a href="#"><img class="img__logo" src="http://placehold.it/169x160" alt="" title=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="hgroup">
              <h1 class="headline__bold headline">Company</h1>
              <h2 class="headline__light headline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor.<br> Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <nav class="navigation__container">
          <button class="btn-toggle" id="btnToggle" aria-label="Open / Close Menu">
                            <span class="line"></span>
                            <span class="line"></span>
                            <span class="line"></span>
                        </button>

          <div class="unboxing__trick">
            <div class="nav">
              <ul class="nav__list">
                <li class="nav__item">
                  <a class="nav__link active" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__item">
                  <a class="nav__link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__item">
                  <a class="nav__link" href="#">Calendar</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__item">
                  <a class="nav__link" href="#">Workshops</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__item">
                  <a class="nav__link" href="#">Lecture</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__item nav__item--has-dropdown">
                  <a class="nav__link arrow" href="#">Article</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li class="nav__item dropdown__item">
                      <a href="#" class="nav__link dropdown__link">Article Title First</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav__item dropdown__item">
                      <a href="#" class="nav__link dropdown__link">Article Title Second</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav__item dropdown__item">
                      <a href="#" class="nav__link dropdown__link">Article Title Third</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav__item dropdown__item">
                      <a href="#" class="nav__link dropdown__link">Article Title Fourth</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__item">
                  <a class="nav__link" href="#">Audio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__item">
                  <a class="nav__link" href="#">Youtube</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__item">
                  <a class="nav__link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__item social__icon">
                  <figure class="icon__container">
                    <div class="icon">
                      <a class="social__link social__link--fb" href="#">
                        <svg version="1.1" id="Social_Icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="-297.5 123.5 595 595" enable-background="new -297.5 123.5 595 595" reserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xml:space="preserve">
                                                        <rect x="-64.47" y="206.101" fill="#FFFFFF" width="276.871" height="512.399"/>
                                                        <path id="Facebook" fill="#4460A0" d="M20.309,718.5H-264.66c-18.143,0-32.84-14.707-32.84-32.84V156.342
                                                         c0-18.144,14.698-32.842,32.84-32.842h529.324c18.135,0,32.836,14.698,32.836,32.842V685.66c0,18.137-14.701,32.84-32.836,32.84
                                                         H113.042V488.082h77.34l11.581-89.799h-88.921v-57.328c0-26,7.218-43.713,44.5-43.713l47.548-0.02v-80.316
                                                         c-8.223-1.092-36.449-3.538-69.289-3.538c-68.561,0-115.496,41.851-115.496,118.698v66.222H-57.23v89.798H20.31V718.5H20.309z"/>
                                                    </svg>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon">
                      <a class="social__link social__link--youtube" href="#">
                        <svg version="1.1" id="Social_Icons" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 36.305 595 595" enable-background="new 0 36.305 595 595" reserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xml:space="preserve">
                                                        <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="214.04,443.136 214.04,214.49 432.938,328.812 "/>
                                                            <path id="Youtube" fill="#CE1312" d="M589.05,214.115c0,0-5.819-41.248-23.65-59.408c-22.629-23.849-47.991-23.959-59.611-25.343
                                                                c-83.265-6.06-208.158-6.06-208.158-6.06h-0.261c0,0-124.895,0-208.157,6.06c-11.641,1.384-36.984,1.495-59.63,25.343
                                                                C11.75,172.873,5.948,214.115,5.948,214.115S0,262.565,0,310.993v45.417c0,48.445,5.949,96.875,5.949,96.875
                                                                s5.802,41.247,23.633,59.407c22.647,23.851,52.379,23.102,65.617,25.591c47.6,4.602,202.301,6.021,202.301,6.021
                                                                s125.024-0.185,208.288-6.246c11.621-1.4,36.983-1.514,59.611-25.36c17.831-18.166,23.652-59.408,23.652-59.408
                                                                S595,404.859,595,356.41v-45.417C595,262.565,589.05,214.115,589.05,214.115z M236.066,411.443l-0.019-168.18l160.762,84.38
                                                                L236.066,411.443z"/>
                                                    </svg>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </figure>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </section>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

My code at [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZjjBYq)

Comment: _“But now I have a problem with setting the last menu `<li>` items with social icons.”_ — what specifically is the problem?

Comment: At 768px resolution, it does not work right, with the dropdown submenu, the last li item menu with social icons, can't be seen. How to make it visible without setting it rigidly because as I mentioned earlier links in the dropdown submenu will be added dynamically.

Comment: Works fine for me, using Firefox Nightly 63.0a1.

Comment: I use Firefox Developer Edition. But the site has to adapt to all browsers.